# Can't install Xubuntu with unetbootin from hardrive

Tags: intel, vaio, unetbootin

I have no dvd or usb and I'm trying to install Xubuntu with unetbootin from hardrive. I have 120gb hardrive with 3 partition: Win7, Swap, and one for Xubuntu

First I do this

[image]

and get the following error:

[image]

I have tried with with ex2, ex4, ex3 but get the same error.

Comment: Yes you surely can, but this is why you shouldn't do it: You'll be installing the LIVE version of the OS not the Full fledged installed OS into your drive.

Comment: I would suggest wubi would be a better option.

Comment: You need to copy the installer from the ISO onto a different drive than where you are installing it to--The installer cannot work on a drive currently in use.(See notification in first screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like from your side there is no fault.But you can give a try to below instruction..

Sometimes copying files from one place to another place or downloading from the download manager by pausing or unpausing.. break the original file(a.k.a accidental corruption)..so always compare the md5sum values.

To do so open your terminal:

1) change directory to the location of your file

`cd to/your/iso/file/location`

2) Then type the following command

`md5sum kubuntu-your-version.iso`

md5sum should then print out a single line after calculating the hash:

`8044d756b7f00b695ab8dce07dce43e5 xubuntu-your-version.iso`

3) Now go to this link [UBUNTU HASHES](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes).. `This page contains all of the md5 hashes for the different versions of Ubuntu,Kubuntu, Edubuntu, Xubuntu and Lubuntu`.

4) copy the hash value from the terminal and search in the browser by pressing (ctrl+F)
..

`if there is no match ..`

then surely your xubuntu file is corrupted.consider downloading the new iso

`else`

xubuntu file is fine. Error might be related to disk partition.

Comment: im not able to do that from unetbootin. cause i have no access to win7. but i did it in win7 with checksum and hash value is right.

Comment: If you read the error message in the first screenshot, you will see that your solution does not apply.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS  read carefully again man.. it just a warning that you should not do anything in /dev/sda2 partition which is from where you are trying to install ... please correct me if i am wrong. thanks.

Comment: @uriahheep Is `/dev/sda2` mounted?